# java closure workaround

Tags: java

I have 5 buttons and I need to iterate over them to carry out some initialization actions as shown in the code below. However, Java prevents me from passing i to the function ScreenFactory.produce() since it is not final due to some closure problem that I read about. I can not make it final since then it would prevent the increment in the loop. What is the solution?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            levelButtons[i].setAction(ActionType.GENERAL_ACTION, new GameAction() {

                @Override
                public void execute(int screenID) {
                    Game.instance.changeScreen( ScreenFactory.produce(ScreenFactory.GAME_SCREEN, i));
                }
            });

            TouchHandler.instance.register(levelButtons[i]);
        }
```

Comment: a simple workaround would be to create a final variable inside of your closure and assign it the value of `i`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: post it as an answer...

Comment: How would I assign it to i? The same problem: i is not final

Comment: @wirate You can assign non final values to final variables, otherwise _no_ final varaibles would ever be able to get a value.

Comment: got it. I thought he was telling me to do it inside the anonymous class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple workaround would be to create a final variable inside of your closure and assign it the value of `i`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
{
   final int finalI = i;
   levelButtons[i].setAction(ActionType.GENERAL_ACTION, new GameAction() 
   {
       @Override
       public void execute(int screenID) 
       {
         Game.instance.changeScreen( ScreenFactory.produce(ScreenFactory.GAME_SCREEN, finalI));
       }
    });
    TouchHandler.instance.register(levelButtons[i]);
}
```

Comment: i is still not final in execute() and cant be used.

Comment: Indeed, it needs to be finalI in this example.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a temporary variable (e.g. `tmp`) inside the loop that you mark `final`, initialize it with the value of `i` and pass `tmp` to the `produce()` call

Answer (score 0):

Load i into another variable before passing it to the ScreenFactory.